# Nullable object must have a value in Linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq, null

Why would a nullable int give this error using linq?

```
public void test(int? variableId)
{
     var date = _dbContext.Set<MyEvent>()
              .Where(x => x.Calendar.id == (variableId.HasValue ? variableId   : x.Calendar.id))
              .ToList();
}
```

- variableId.HasValue is false
- variableId is null

Comment: Are all your Calenders != null?

Comment: Yes, my Calendars are Not nullable

Comment: variableId.HasValue and variableId != null both are same, so if your variable Id is null then variableId.HasValue will always be false, it will show a true value when you have some value in the nullable int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it as (variableId.HasValue ? variableId.**Value** : x.Calendar.id)

Assuming variableId is null, then you have a very funny expression .Where(x => x.Calendar.id == x.Calendar.id) that means - all records. The problem with your code is that having your original where expression most likely cause client side filtering but not sql side filtering. It is better to rewrite it like:

```
var date = variableId.HasValue
      ?_dbContext.Set<MyEvent>().Where(x => x.Calendar.id == variableId.Value))
      :_dbContext.Set<MyEvent>();
```